# Change the default value of a checkbox element

Tags: forms

I created 7 checkboxes which to be selected by default. To achieve this, I implemented `hook_form_alter()` using the following code.

```php
function module_form_webform_client_form_31_after_build($element, &$form_state) {dpm($element);
  $element['submitted']['checkbox7'][1]['#checked'] = TRUE;
  $element['submitted']['checkbox6'][1]['#checked'] = TRUE;
  $element['submitted']['checkbox5'][1]['#checked'] = TRUE;
  $element['submitted']['checkbox4'][1]['#checked'] = TRUE;
  $element['submitted']['checkbox3'][1]['#checked'] = TRUE;
  $element['submitted']['checkbox2'][1]['#checked'] = TRUE;
  $element['submitted']['checkbox1'][1]['#checked'] = TRUE;

  return $element;
}
```

This code works fine for me.

Is there a way to change the default value of all the checkboxes without adding a new line for each new checkbox I could later add?

Comment: Try this out. if ($form_id=='webform_client_form_31') { $element['submitted'][''][1]['#default_value'] = TRUE; }

Comment: This is a wild guess. How do you expect it to work? For Drupal `$element['submitted']['']` doesn't mean _all the checkbox elements in the form_.

Answer (score 1):

This code find the checkboxes in the 'submitted' element and check it by default.
If you make a screenshot of dsm($element['submitted']) message I can check if this code is correct ^^

```
function module_form_webform_client_form_31_after_build($element, &$form_state) {
  foreach ($element['submitted'] as $key => &$value) {
    if ( $value['#type'] == 'checkbox' ) {
      $element['submitted'][$key][1]['#checked'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code?

```
function module_form_webform_client_form_31_after_build($element, &$form_state) {
  foreach ($element['submitted'] as $key => &$value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'checkbox')) {
      $value[1]['#checked'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
  return $element;
}
```